# How can we build explicit categories in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

Corresponding with the mathematical idea of a category, Haskell has a [Category typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html). I'd like to build some small finite categories and work with them, along the lines of [the book Computational Category Theory](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/%7Edavid/categories/book/book.pdf) but with better type-checking.

For example, in math there is a small but important category called the "terminal category", which has exactly one object, and one arrow which is that object's identity. Here's my best attempt:

```
data TcObjectType = TcObject
data TcArrowType a0 a1 where
  TcArrow :: TcObjectType -> TcObjectType -> TcArrowType TcObjectType TcObjectType
instance Category TcArrowType where
  id TcObject = TcArrow TcObject TcObject
  (TcArrow TcObject TcObject) . (TcArrow TcObject TcObject) = TcArrow TcObject TcObject
```

The current error is `Couldn't match expected type ‘TcArrowType a a’ with actual type ‘TcObjectType -> TcArrowType TcObjectType TcObjectType’`. `TcArrow TcObject TcObject` is supposed to be the value representing the unique arrow, but for some reason, the compiler seems to be treating it as a function.

**Is there a reasonable way to do this?**

**Edit**: I want to describe any finite category, not just the terminal category. This means I want to say explicitly that arrow X goes from object A to object B. Probably the next example would be the category with two objects and two parallel arrows between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** See https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/d5347d06dfcfc1d8ce796bb2966b3343 for a full, compiling, safe version.

---

The problem is the `Control.Category.id` is required to quantify *over all* types of the given kind:

```
class Category c where
  id :: ∀ a . c a a
  ...
```

IOW, if the object are of kind `Type` (as your `TcObject` is), then a `Category` instance must have *all* Haskell types as objects, which of course immediately disqualifies the terminal category as an instance.

There are several different alternative category classes around that allows specifying a *constraint* on the choice of objects; with [`constrained-categories`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Category) the instance would look thus:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds    #-}

import qualified Control.Category.Constrained.Class as CC

instance CC.Category TcArrowType where
  type Object TcArrowType a = a ~ TcObjectType
  id = TcArrow TcObject TcObject
  TcArrow TcObject TcObject . TcArrow TcObject TcObject = TcArrow TcObject TcObject
```

But there's an arguably more elegant alternative: since your object isn't really used as a type at all (you use it as a type to tag the arrows with runtime values, but that information is redundant), there's no point having it be of kind `Type` in the first place. Indeed the standard `Category` class is *poly-kinded* (which is not really evident from the documentation), and therefore you can use instead of your `data TcObjectType = TcObject` a *lifted data constructor* to express the same thing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

data TcObjectKind = TcObject
data TcArrowType (a₀ :: TcObjectKind) (a₁ :: TcObjectKind) where
  TcArrow :: TcArrowType 'TcObject 'TcObject
instance Category TcArrowType where
  id = TcArrow
  TcArrow . TcArrow = TcArrow
```

...or at least that's how it would conceptually look. Actually this doesn't *quite* work, because although `TcObject` *is* the only type<sup>†</sup> of kind `TcObjectKind`, the compiler does not automatically infer that `o ~ TcObject` for every `o :: TcObjectKind`. But you can manually tell it:

```
import Unsafe.Coerce

instance Category TcArrowType where
  id = unsafeCoerce TcArrow    -- Safe because `a` can only ever be `TcObject`.
```

@dfeuer remarks that this is actually not *quite* safe because of a quirk in how GHC handles type families vs type constructors, see https://gist.github.com/treeowl/6104ef553dadf0d1faf01da0850ddb01. IMO this is not `unsafeCoerce`s fault but GHC's, but still this isn't exactly a nice solution.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>To be pedantic it's not a type, but a type-level value.</sub>

---

For more sophisticated work and categories with more objects&arrows than the terminal category, you'll want to make this a bit more disciplined instead of manual `unsafeCoerce` in `id`. This is essentially the problem that [*singletons*](https://blog.jle.im/entry/introduction-to-singletons-1.html) are supposed to solve.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, GADTs              #-}

import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d|
   data TcObjectKind = TcObject
  |])

data TcArrowType (a₀ :: TcObjectKind) (a₁ :: TcObjectKind) where
  TcArrow :: TcArrowType 'TcObject 'TcObject

tcId :: ∀ a . SingI a => TcArrowType a a
tcId = case sing :: Sing a of
  STcObject -> TcArrow
```

This now generalises to categories with multiple objects, like

```
$(singletons [d|
   data Trap = Free | Trapped
  |])

data TrapArrowType (a₀ :: Trap) (a₁ :: Trap) where
  StillFree :: TrapArrowType 'Free 'Free
  Falling :: TrapArrowType 'Free 'Trapped
  Stuck :: TrapArrowType 'Trapped 'Trapped

trapId :: ∀ a . SingI a => TrapArrowType a a
trapId = case sing :: Sing a of
  SFree -> StillFree
  STrapped -> Stuck
```

Unfortunately, with singletons we're back at the problem that we have a `SingI a` constraint that the base `Category` class cannot provide. But again, the `constrained-categories` version can.

Comment: The second approach looks nice, but the compiler is choking on the `id` line: `• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘'TcObject’`, `‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for: Control.Category.id :: forall (a :: TcObjectKind). TcArrowType a a at cat.hs:34:3-4`, `Expected type: TcArrowType a a`, `Actual type: TcArrowType 'TcObject 'TcObject`. Perhaps there is another magic language option to handle this?

Comment: Ah yes. I don't think a language option helps you with that, but `unsafeCoerce` does.

Comment: @HewWolff, unfortunately this is actually very unsafe, thanks to the peculiar feature of *stuck type families*. See [this code](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/6104ef553dadf0d1faf01da0850ddb01) "proving" that `'True :~: 'False`, which could easily be used to produce segfaults.

Comment: Actually, it'd be even easier to make segfaults by using exactly the same technique to "prove" that `Int :~: String` or similar.

Comment: Why not just use `data TcArrowType (a₀ :: TcObjectKind) (a₁ :: TcObjectKind) where
  TcArrow :: TcArrowType a a
instance Category TcArrowType where
  id = TcArrow; ...`?

Comment: @dfeuer hm, yeah, but I do prefer how `TcArrow :: TcArrowType 'TcObject 'TcObject` makes the structure of the category completely explicit.

Comment: Well, if you're okay with letting me recover full on `unsafeCoerce`.....

Comment: This is all interesting, and I do see the terminal category compiling now from @dfeuer's suggestion, but is there a way to extend this to other categories? In general we will want to say that arrow X goes from object A to object B. I'll edit to make this clearer.

Comment: I think you should really remove the false safety claim from your answer, and replace it by an explanation of why this is *not* safe.

Comment: @dfeuer ? — Feel free to elaborate on non-safety; I don't see it. For the one-object case, that is. For multiple objects, neither `TcArrow :: TcArrowType a a` nor `unsafeCoerce` does the trick. — As per the edit, I think singletons are really the proper way to go about this, however they incur a `SingI` instance which prevents writing a standard `Category` instance. But I might be missing something; not that firm with singletons.

Comment: Thanks for the new ideas, I'll look at those. By the way, I also looked into constrained-categories. but found that `cabal install constrained-categories` brought the error `Ambiguous occurrence ‘MonadFail’`.

Comment: @HewWolff aw that, yeah, that has actually been [fixed for a while](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories/pull/3) but not been updated on Hackage. With [the latest version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0) it should now work also on GHC-8.8.

Comment: @HewWolff https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/d5347d06dfcfc1d8ce796bb2966b3343

Comment: Nice, thanks! Next I will try to write some explicit functors. :-)